How to speed up parallel list processing
I am trying to solve a problem: there is a list of strings, each string must be processed separately. Each string is processed in about 40-50 ms, and if there are 200 strings in the list, it is already about a second, which is a lot.
I'm trying to find a way to speed up processing using parallelization. At first I tried to do it through CompletableFuture, but in another question the experts said that this was not the optimal way. I tried other ways and wrote a Benchmark. According to my results, it turns out that the best option is CompletableFuture with FixedThreadPool.
Results:
Benchmark                                              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkCompletableFuture              thrpt    9  0,430 ± 0,001  ops/s
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkCompletableFutureWithExecutor  thrpt    9  3,848 ± 0,010  ops/s
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkForkJoin                       thrpt    9  0,437 ± 0,024  ops/s
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkParallel                       thrpt    9  0,423 ± 0,008  ops/s
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkCompletableFuture               avgt    9  2,326 ± 0,010   s/op
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkCompletableFutureWithExecutor   avgt    9  0,260 ± 0,001   s/op
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkForkJoin                        avgt    9  2,286 ± 0,122   s/op
TaskBenchmark.benchmarkParallel                        avgt    9  2,360 ± 0,018   s/op

In the solution CompletableFutureWithExecutor, I don't like that 100 threads are installed, since some of the tasks are waiting in the queue. But it seems that increasing to 500 threads is not a good idea.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Or is there another more optimal way?
PS: doWork method simulates string processing. This method cannot be optimized because it will make a blocking call to a third-party service..
CompletableFuture:
public class ComputableFutureExample implements AutoCloseable {
   private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

    public List<String> handle(List<String> records) {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String record : records) {
            CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> WorkUtil.doWork(record));
            futures.add(future);
        }

        return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenApply(v -> futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .join();
    }

    public List<String> handleWithExecutor(List<String> records) {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String record : records) {
            CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> WorkUtil.doWork(record), executor);
            futures.add(future);
        }

        return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenApply(v -> futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .join();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}


RecursiveTask:
public class RecordTask extends RecursiveTask<List<String>> {
    private final List<String> records;

    public RecordTask(List<String> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> compute() {
        if (records.size() > 1) {
            return ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(createSubtasks())
                    .stream()
                    .map(ForkJoinTask::join)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .toList();
        } else {
            return processing(records);
        }
    }

    private Collection<RecordTask> createSubtasks() {
        List<RecordTask> dividedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        dividedTasks.add(new RecordTask(
                records.subList(0, records.size() / 2)));
        dividedTasks.add(new RecordTask(
                records.subList(records.size() / 2, records.size())));
        return dividedTasks;
    }

    private List<String> processing(List<String> records) {
        return records.stream().map(WorkUtil::doWork).toList();
    }

}

public class WorkUtil {
    public static String doWork(String record) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return record + " completed";
    }
}

Benchmark:
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 3, time = 5)
@BenchmarkMode({Mode.AverageTime, Mode.Throughput})
@Fork(value = 3)
public class TaskBenchmark {
    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class DataProvider {
        private List<String> records;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setup() {
            this.records = IntStream.range(0, 500).mapToObj(i -> UUID.randomUUID().toString() + i).toList();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void benchmarkForkJoin(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        RecordTask recordTask = new RecordTask(dataProvider.records);
        try (ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool()) {
            forkJoinPool.invoke(recordTask);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void benchmarkCompletableFuture(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        try (ComputableFutureExample example = new ComputableFutureExample();) {
            example.handle(dataProvider.records);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void benchmarkCompletableFutureWithExecutor(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        try (ComputableFutureExample example = new ComputableFutureExample();) {
            example.handleWithExecutor(dataProvider.records);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void benchmarkParallel(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        dataProvider.records.parallelStream().map(WorkUtil::doWork).toList();
    }
}


So you have a list of Strings and you want to process the Strings. The method to "process" the Strings is Thread.sleep for 50ms. You want to know what is the fastest way?

@matt I wrote that "doWork method simulates string processing. This method cannot be optimized because it will result in a blocking call to a third-party service."In the current implementation, I don't like that in order to quickly process a list of 500 strings, I need to create 500 threads

Testing using Thread.sleep isn't going to give any realistic measures, especially if you later try virtual threads.

You could use virtual threads. They are made to be lightweight and disposable. Since your task isn't CPU bound it works well.
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
public class Workem{

    static String work(String s){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch( Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<1000000; i++){
            strings.add("id: " + i);
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        List<Callable<String>> r = strings.stream().map( str ->(Callable<String>)() -> work(str) ).toList();
        Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor().invokeAll(r);
        System.out.println("finished: " + ((System.nanoTime() - start)*1e-9) );
        
    }

}

